# Нужно увеличить дату на 1 секунду, если она равна предыдущей

Tags: sql

подскажите пожалуйста как увеличить в таблице (Access) дату на 1 сек, если она равна предыдущей. Проблема в таблице много строк с одинаковой датой (с точностью до 1 мин) нужно их разделить, хотя бы секундой.

Спасибо.

Comment: *если она равна предыдущей* А как различать, какая предыдущая, а какая не очень, если у них время - одинаковое?

Comment: Задача-то одноразовая небось?

Answer (score 0):

Будет нечто типа

```sql
UPDATE source_table t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.datetime, MIN(t2.id) AS id
       FROM source_table t2
       GROUP BY t2.datetime
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) AS t3
SET t1.datetime = DateAdd("s", t1.id - t3.id, t1.datetime)
```

Если, конечно, Access не заартачится - не люблит он группировки в подзапросах при обновлениях...

Comment: а в access не надо условия join задавать?

Comment: @splash58 Надо, конечно... но я вообще сомневаюсь, что заработает. Так, подкинул как идею, откуда взять прибавку - не в комментарий же такое пихать. А то счас дадут очевидный ответ - а у автора окажется ТРИ записи с одинаковым временем...

Comment: А что такое t2 это какая-то другая таблица? У меня одна таблица. Записей с одинаковым временем у меня несколько десятков тысяч.

Comment: t2 - это алиас (псевдоним) таблицы - надо же как-то различать несколько копий одной и той же таблицы...